# Rounded corners hack - what am doing wrong here?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have implemented a .htc behaviour to try and get rounded corners for IE-6-8 from here:
http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Can't seem to get it to work, even after following all the little IE methods it recommends.

```
#callbox {
position:relative;
background-image:url(images/callbox_bg.png);
width:360px;
height:75px;
float:right;
padding:10px 20px 0px 10px;
font-size:26px;

display:block;


border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;


behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
zoom:1;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in CSS the url path is relative to the document. With .htc files though it needs to relative to the site root.

Take the following site structure:

```
Root
   - images/
      - image.png
   - css/
      - layout.css
- index.html
- border-radius.htc
```

To use an image in your layout.css files your url would be `('../images/image.png')`
To use the .htc file it would be `('../border-radius.htc')`

Also (and this might not be relevant) but to get CSS3PIE.htc working you need to add position: relative to the styles.

Comment: Hi. Have moved the .htc to the root folder and changed css path to:

behavior: url(../border-radius.htc);

Still no luck though :( Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Is border-radius.htc actually ON the site root? I'd imagine that would make your css - url(border-radius.htc) wouldn't it?

Comment: It has to be on the root btw.

Comment: Worked! It was a stray / in the path... thanks for your help!

Comment: Thought so. This had me stumped for a long time too. Please remember to accept this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In their example they have `border-radius: 15px;` *after* `behavior`. See if that works or you. Also look at the list of caveats for IE an make sure not of them apply to your layout.

```
.rounded-corners {
    behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Have changed it so the border-radius is after, no change.
I've gone through the list and applied it to this callbox div so I don't know what else to do!

Answer (score 1):

It looks okay to me, are you sure that the htc file path is correct i.e. it is accessible via `http://example.com/css/boarder-radius.htc`?